# How to make multiple nested http requests with promises and async/await while web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise

Below I have a Node.js function that makes a series of requests to different urls, then for each url I use the Cheerio web scraping library to loop through elements on the dom and create a sub array. At the end of each request (after the sub array is full) I'd like to push the contents of that array to a larger array, which is outside of the request scope.

The approach I'm trying doesn't seem to be working. It looks like I don't have access to 'allPlayers' from inside the .then block.

```
function readPlayers(teamUrls){

    const allPlayers = [];

    teamUrls.forEach((teamUrl, i) => { 

        const options = {
            gzip: true,
            uri: teamUrl,
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            transform: function (body) {
                return cheerio.load(body);
            }
        };

        request(options)
        .then(($) => {

            const team = [];

                $('tbody').children('tr').each(function(j, element){            

                     const playerName = $(element).children('td').eq(1).children('span').eq(1).find('a').text().trim();

                     const player = { 'playerName': playerName };

                     team.push(player);

                 });

            allPlayers.push(team);

        }).catch(err => console.log("error: " + err)) );

    });

}
```

So I'm wondering the best way to re-write this code to make the requests work and populate the outer array (allPlayers) with the results.

I've looked into trying to push the entire request directly into the outer array, to no avail.

In this example I'm using request-promise to make the request.

I've looked into using Promise.map, which I think is suited for this situation. Then I would return the entire request (I think), but I don't exactly understand what I'm doing in that case.. or if it will work.

Could anyone explain the scoping in this case, why I can't do it like I'm trying.

Many thanks

Comment: I didn't get why you have a dollar sign in the `then` statement - `.then(($) => {`

Comment: thats just the DOM returned from the cheerio web scraper request.. (I think that's the way jquery does it which is how the docs had it). It could easily be re-named 'DOM' or something else

Comment: is the `request` here `request-promise`? because the original `request` lib doesn't return a promise

Comment: yes, I'll update the question. I'm using request promise native

Comment: You definitely do have the access to the `allPlayers` inside your closure (inside the `then` block). You could be just trying to consume the supposed result prematurely.

Comment: Replace `forEach` with `map`, instead of pushing just return the result and put `Promise.all` in front of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember when you are using asynchronous function you cannot go back to synchronous code execution.

This is one of the methods you can do it. It will fetch all the players parallely:

```
async function readPlayers(teamUrls) {
   const playerPromises = teamUrls.map((teamUrl, i) => {
    const options = {
      gzip: true,
      uri: teamUrl,
      Connection: 'keep-alive',
      transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      }
    };
    return request(options)
  });

  const players = await Promise.all(playerPromises);
  return players.reduce((allPlayers, $) =>{
    const team = [];
    $('tbody').children('tr').each(function(j, element) {
      const playerName = $(element).children('td').eq(1).children('span').eq(1).find('a').text().trim();
      const player = { playerName: playerName };
      team.push(player);
    });
    allPlayers.push(team);
    return allPlayers;
  },[])
}
```

And you can use it using `await readPlayers(array)` or `readPlayers(array).then(allteamplayers=>{...})`

**Note:** In the current code it will be a 2D array, [[{p1:p1}..], [{p2:p2}..]] etc

Comment: great answer, if the synchronous code is nested won't it still work (like Elias's answer above?)

Comment: yeah it will work No problems. personally i like my async calls and processors(or the bussiness logic) different. it's easy to refactor. You can take out the http call to other function and processor in other function. Your processor can be a class which has multiple types of processors. If u isolate those two, they become atomic and independent.

Comment: So a logical separation would be, `fetchPlayers()`, and `getPlayerName()`.

Comment: Partly agreeing with Aritra, separation of concerns is a design principle that makes it easier to refactor, extend and test code. Perhaps a good refactoring would be to extract your .then callback in a processPlayers function.

Comment: Exactly ^ @EliasFaraone

Comment: @ Aritra I'm still a little confused on the above answer. Where you wrote 'players.reduce(allPlayers.. '  I'm assuming allPlayers is the previously declared array (and your code is missing that line)? Also, I get an error with [] as the third param.  I tried looking at .reduce, but I'm still not that familiar. Could you help me understand a little better? Thx

Comment: In reduce the first param is a callback function and second param is the accumulator(collector). The callback function takes 4 params first is the collector of sort(that is basically the last param), second current element, third index 4th is the entire array. also I had a typo in my script. the enclosing bracket.

Comment: It's much appreciated, I understand reduce better now. I'm still getting one little error, the dom element ($) inside of .reduce doesn't seem to be making its way through right. When I try to use it with $('tbody')... I'm getting red underline "This expression is not callable. Type '{}' has no call signatures." Any ideas?

Comment: got it! I just had to change the params to (allPlayers : any, $ : any)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a forEach, every callback will run asynchronously and you won't be able to await them. You could swap it to a for loop, collect your promises in an array and then await the completion of all of them:

```
async function readPlayers(teamUrls) {
  const allPlayers = [];
  const allPromises = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < teamUrls.length; i++) {
    var teamUrl = teamUrls[i];

    const options = {
      gzip: true,
      uri: teamUrl,
      Connection: "keep-alive",
      transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      }
    };

    allPromises.push(
      request(options)
        .then($ => {
          const team = [];
          $("tbody")
            .children("tr")
            .each(function(j, element) {
              const playerName = $(element)
                .children("td")
                .eq(1)
                .children("span")
                .eq(1)
                .find("a")
                .text()
                .trim();
              const player = { playerName: playerName };
              team.push(player);
            });

          allPlayers.push(team);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("error: " + err))
    );

    // wait untill all the promises resolve
    await Promise.all(allPromises);

    console.log(allPlayers);

    return allPlayers;
  }
}
```

Then you can get all the players by awaiting your function:

```
var allPlayers = await readPlayers(teamUrls);
```

Comment: Sure, when you use await in a function you need to make that asynchronous. forEach takes a callBack function, but will always call the function like callBack(element) without awaiting it! so the callBack is synchronous inside of itself, but as a whole will still run asynchronously meaning the code that calls the forEach loop gets to continue before those callBacks complete.

Comment: so, to recap, forEach does "callBack(element)", but you want "await callBack(element)". To do that, the easiest way is to instead use a "for" loop where you can specify how you call that callBack

Comment: appreciate that